# How to make web app like "Epic Sax Gandalf" using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I want to create an application that when launched on different devices will display the same content (music, photo or video) at the same time.

[Here is simple example.](https://watwat.netlify.com/)

[And real-life example. :)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9WF8ZtMbrA)

My first idea was based on machine local time.

```
timestamp = new Date().getTime()
(timestamp(\d{4}$) === "0000") => play music and animation
```

music = 10s,
animation = 10s

and for every every 10 seconds, start this function.

I know, however, that this solution may not work and the content will still be unsynchronized.

So, does anyone know how to achieve the effect I'm talking about using javascript?

Comment: Why JavaScript though? Have a `<img>` tag and a `<audio>` tag and you're done. Just check out the source of the example. No need to bring JavaScript into the fold here.

Comment: Yes, I know because the example is mine. ;) the problem is that there is a lack of synchronization on many devices.

Comment: Mate, if you want it to get synchronized like that, then you need to base the image animation on your server's time. Once the page loads you need to send a request to the server asking for the "time". You need to also calculate the latency (aka how long the request took) and then subtract that time from the time sent from your server. That'll give you the current time. Then with the time you can calculate which frame you need to start on in your gandalf video.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same idea as you had and implemented a little [proof of concept for it](https://github.com/Dassderdie/synchronized-sax-gandalf).

You can try it out like this:

1. [Open the deployed site](https://synchronized-sax-gandalf.netlify.app/) (either in two browsers/windows or even on different devices)
2. Choose the same unique channel-id for all your opened sites
3. Click "Start"
4. One window should have a heading with "Leader". The others should be "Follower"s. By clicking on the Video-id field you can paste the video id of any youtube video (or choose from a small list of recommended ones).
5. Click "Play" on each window
6. Wait a bit - it can take up to 1 minute until the videos synchronize
7. Each follower has a "System time offset". On the same device it should be nearly 0ms. This is the time that the system-time (`Date.now()`) in the browser differs from the system time on the Leader window.
8. On the top left of each video you can see a time that changes every few seconds and should be under 20ms (after the videos are synchronized). This is the time the video-feed differs from its optimal time in relation to the system time.

(I would love to know wether it works for you too. My Pusher deployment is EU-based so maybe problems with the increased latency could occur...)

How does it work?

The synchronisation happens in two steps:

Step 1.: Synchronizing the system times

I basically implemented the [NTP (Network time protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) Algorithm in JS via websockets or [Pusher JS](https://pusher.com/) as my channel of communication between each Follower- and the Leader-clients. Look under "Clock synchronization algorithm" in the Wikipedia article for more information.

Step 2.: Synchronizing the video feed to the "reference time"

At the `currentTime` (= synchronized system time) we want the `currentVideoTime`to be at `currentTime % videoLength`. Because the `currentTime` or system time has been synchronized between the clients in Step 1 and the `videoLength` is obviously the same in all the clients (because they are supposed to play the same video) the `currentVideoTime` is the same too.

The big problem is that if I would just start the video at the correct time on all clients (via `setTimeout()`) they probably wouldn't play at the same time, because one system has e.g. network problems and the video still buffers or another program wants in this moment the processing power of the OS. Depending on the device the time from calling the start function of the video player and the actual starting of the video differs too.

I'm solving this by checking every second wether the video is at the right position (= `currentTime % videoLength`). If the difference to the right position is bigger than 20ms, I'm stopping the video, skipping the video to the position where it should be in 5s + the time it was late before and start it again.

The code is a bit more sophisticated (and complicated) but this is the general idea.

[sync-difference-estimator](https://github.com/Dassderdie/synchronized-sax-gandalf/blob/ec72c8522ecc917dee91b8d9d36f08427f7b97c7/client/src/app/shared/player/sync-difference-estimator.ts#L1)

[synchronized-player](https://github.com/Dassderdie/synchronized-sax-gandalf/blob/ec72c8522ecc917dee91b8d9d36f08427f7b97c7/client/src/app/shared/player/synchronized-player.ts)